# C/C++ method parameter hints in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, parameters

is there any way how to enable Eclipse to show hints for parameters of C/C++ functions.
When I press Ctrl + Shift + Space it shows only types of parameters but not the names.
And is there also any way Eclipse can show parameter hints automatically when ( is pressed?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the CDT plugin?  If so which version?  The following applies to Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) with the CDT plugin.  If your setup is different then the rest of this answer may not be accurate.

`Ctrl + Space` brings up the type and names of parameters for me.

Looking through the preferences (Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Content Assist )  there's an Auto-Activation panel.  There's 3 triggers available, `.`, `::` and `->`

Typing `this->` and waiting 200ms brings up a list of auto-complete options.  This list contains the methods and shows both the type and name of the parameters (if the name is available)

The same applies to `foo.` where `foo` is an object and `bar->` where `bar` is a pointer.

If you're talking about when you're implementing a method, then the same applies.  `Foo::` + `Ctrl + Space` brings up the list of available items, including methods and shows parameter types and names.

Comment: In IntelliJ I can press Ctrl-P when the cursor is over an argument in a written out function. That way I can get a list of what argument types to put in. I can't find the same very convenient feature in Eclipse unfortunately. Does it exist?